# Borrow from a git branch without inviting damage to your own later commit

Tags: git, merge, branch

I want to be able to pick and choose code-segments from another branch (of a big project); to adopt those in my own branch; to change some of them; without surrendering the owner of the other branch's prior claim on them; so that when s/he commits, their commit readily supersedes my changes to their code, but doesn't supersede my changes to my own.

Although I've been programming for a couple of decades, I am relatively a git 'newbie'.  I used to use Subversion, TFS (I know .. don't sigh ... :) ).

In a previous job I made a mess for myself.

I and a colleague were working on similar problems.  He was writing some foundations which my implementation needed to rely on.  We each had independent git branches.

His work wasn't progressing as quickly as I needed it to.  In order to begin to join up my super-structure to his foundation, I asked him to commit his current state-of-play (incomplete feature).  My plan was to adopt what worked, and sketch in some alternative implementations for what had yet to be done.  I expected him to overwrite my sketches, when he pushed to master, later on.

Somewhere later I pushed to master.

What actually happened was quite different from my hope ... :)  Work in my local working copy built and ran swimmingly.  But when I checked the same work out from master to build a 'from scratch' installation, I discovered that noticeable portions of my commits were no longer present in the source.

I'm not sure what had gone wrong (perhaps git 'finished' my colleague's branch when I merged from it; and perhaps he had to take extraordinary steps to get his to commit; incidentally ditching mine), but that is perhaps unimportant.

Does anyone know what the 'git-hygienic' method is to [choose my words carefully to avoid git jargon] 'acquire' segments of code from another branch, without bringing the panoply of branching and merging metadata with it, please?

Or perhaps there is a git-hygienic method to pick and choose, which does preserve the metadata (and would have allowed my colleague to supersede my alterations to his code, easily)?

[ I have used git graphical tools (Tower Git, Git extensions), but 'when it's all going wrong', I find git-bash the most reliable, the easiest to confirm I'm taking the correct steps in, and the easiest to find reliable forum postings on ]

Comment: Are you asking about cherry-pick? https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Short version: "I don't know".  But it certainly is a hint I should follow up and see whether it offers a good approximation.  I'll go away and experiment, then try to answer .. :)